# Sisense logout with API call

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have problems with logging out user from Sisense.
So I login using jwt and can see my dashboard using SisenseJS.
And now I want to call logout (https://sisense/api/auth/logout). Sisense is located in another server inside same local network so have ip like 10.0.0.45 and I have maped it to "sisense" inside host file. All good.

Then if I just go to browser and put https://sisense/api/auth/logout inside address bar, it works. I also using self-signed certificate so it prompt me to "do you want to continue as this site is not trusted...bla bla bla". But problem starts when I call that endpoint from ajax

```
  $.ajax({
              method: "GET",
              contentType: 'application/json',
             url: "https://sisense/api/auth/logout"
    });
```

(actually I tried to call it from webclient inside controller also, and it does not need to be ajax call anything acceptable). So it returns 403 error. What I am doing wrong? Should I put some headers? Does any one have any experience on it?

Comment: Could you attach the full contents of the 403 error? Also, you might find more details in the `iisnode` logs, usually located under `c:/program files/sisense/prismweb/vnext/iisnode`. Lastly, when you are on the page executing the `ajax` call to `logout`, if you open the developer console can you see the Sisense cookie? (`prism` or `prism_shared`)

Comment: Hi, it does not have those cookies. I tried to manually add those (which is not very good solution) but it still didn't worked. I just think that ajax call not supported for that api (for example in Azure they also does not support ajax call, at least I found one conversation where someone was telling about it).

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working.

So ajax call didn't worked, but redirection was the solution.

Added controller

```
public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            return Redirect("https://sisenseAddress/api/v1/authentication/logout");
        }
```

Also you may need to activate [CORS on Sisesnse](https://documentation.sisense.com/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/)

And as you probably using some SSO like Azure you can put that Logout action url inside Sisense SSO settings as Logout endpoint. So it first do sisense logout and then go back to you site and do lets say Azure logout.